# I am trying to edit object record

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

**Discription:**
Hay, when i trying to edit expenses(model) object it redirect me to income(model) with expenses(model) object id and if income(model) object has same id then it edit income(model) object.Please Help

**ERROR:**
DoesNotExist at /1/

Income matching query does not exist.

model.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Income(models.Model):
    income = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now, null=True)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Expenses(models.Model):
    price = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Food')
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Expenses, Income

class ExpensesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Expenses
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'date_added': 'Date'
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExpensesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_added'].required = False

class IncomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Income
        fields = ('income', 'remark', 'date_added')
```

views.py

```
def addexpenses(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if id == 0:
            form = ExpensesForm()
        else:
            expenses = Expenses.objects.get(id=id)
            form = ExpensesForm(instance=expenses)
        return render(request, 'add expenses.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        if id == 0:
            form = ExpensesForm(request.POST)
        else:
            expenses = Expenses.objects.get(id=id)
            form = ExpensesForm(request.POST, instance=expenses)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('home')

def addincome(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if id == 0:
            form = IncomeForm()
        else:
            income = Income.objects.get(id=id)
            form = IncomeForm(instance=income)
        return render(request, 'add income.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        if id == 0:
            form = IncomeForm(request.POST)
        else:
            income = Income.objects.get(id=id)
            form = IncomeForm(request.POST, instance=income)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', views.addexpenses, name='update-expenses'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.addincome, name='update-income'),
]
```

**Templates**
list income.html

```
{% for income in all_income %}
    <tr>
        <td align="center">{{income.income}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{income.date_added}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{income.remark}}</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="{% url 'update-income' income.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                <i class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
            </a>
            <form action="/deleteincome/{{ income.id }}/" method="post" class="d-inline">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn">
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

list expenses.html

```
{% for expenses in all_expenses %}
    <tr>
        <td align="center">{{expenses.price}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{expenses.category}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{expenses.date_added}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{expenses.remark}}</td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="{% url 'update-expenses' expenses.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                <i class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
            </a>
            <form action="/deleteexpenses/{{ expenses.id }}/" method="post" class="d-inline">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn">
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```